# Stack all the firewood today vs get all the firewood stacked today

Tags: meaning, grammar, verbs, tenses

> 1."Take a rest, Felicia, you don't need to get all the firewood stacked today."
>
> 2."Take a rest, Felicia, you don't need to stack all the firewood today."

What is the difference in meaning between the two examples? Can I use them interchangeably for the same meaning? please refer to example #7[Source:](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/take-a-rest-or-have-some-rest.94833/)

Comment: What research have you done? "Get" + direct object + past participle has a specific meaning; are you aware of how that construction is used?

Comment: No. Please explain it.

Comment: https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5039/how-much-research-is-needed/5043#5043

Answer (score 4):

There is very little difference between "you don't have to get all the firewood stacked" and "you don't have to stack all the firewood today." I do, however, tend to favor the latter expression, if only for the sake of economy of expression.

That is not to say the use of "get" is ungrammatical; rather, it is simply not needed. Assuming Felicia was instructed to perform a specific task of stacking the firewood, which of the following two requests is more economical?

- "Your task today is to stack all the firewood." Or,
- "Your task today is to get all the firewood stacked."

One of Shakespeare's most memorable lines is "Brevity is the soul of wit." In other words, succinctness could be a mark of intelligence, not only in wit, but also in economy of expression in general. Here is some food for thought for you, taken from the website ["No Sweat Shakespeare."](https://nosweatshakespeare.com/quotes/famous/brevity-is-the-soul-of-wit/)

> ‘Brevity is the soul of wit’ is a Shakespeare quote that has become
> one of his most enduring idioms. It is spoken by Polonius, in act 2,
> scene 2 of Hamlet.
>
> In modern times we talk about someone as being witty, and by that we
> mean a person who uses language to say something funny or amusing. But
> we also say things like, ‘she has her wits about her,’ which means
> that she’s pretty bright, and although we are not allowed to say
> ‘half-witted’ about anyone, people still use the term. In those senses
> we get to what the word actually means, which is about how brainy one
> is and how one uses language as a reflection of that.
>
> ‘Brevity’ is the soul of wit’ means that one can say a lot more by
> using the minimum of language to convey something. In other words,
> being brief is the essence of intelligence.

My grandfather used to say, "The more you say, the less the better." His quaint--and deliberately ungrammatical--expression is often true. With fewer words, the danger of being misunderstood is sometimes lessened.

Comment: That is true with one exception: get all that firewood stacked could refer to getting someone else to do it.

Comment: @Lambie: Good point. Don

Answer (score 4):

There is a significant difference between these two expressions:

- *Stack all the firewood* emphasizes the **process**.
- *Get all the firewood stacked* emphasizes the **end state**.

Taken in isolation, the two expressions are closely related, since the commonly-understood way of bringing objects to the state of being *stacked* is to *stack* them.

In a conversation, however, the emphasis on process versus action can tell us something about the speaker’s state of mind, along with their attitude towards Felicia and the need to get the firewood stacked.

Comment: 'Get all the firewood stacked emphasizes the end state' I don't understand what you mean by 'the end state' could you simplify the point please?

Comment: Firewood implies a collection of wood pieces suitable for burning in a stove, fireplace, etc.  Firewood scattered on the ground after delivery (or initial chopping) is in a different *state*  than firewood neatly stacked in a pile.

Comment: 'Stack all the firewood emphasizes the process' I don't understand what you mean by 'the process' here also. Please simplify the point

Comment: The action of stacking wood is a process. It takes the wood from a loosely arranged and “unstacked” state to an orderly arrangement where one row of wood pieces is laid on top of another, several rows deep. Similarly, *chopping wood* is a process. *Delivering wood* is a process.

Comment: Ok, then how do you know that Stack all the firewood is a process and 

Get all the firewood stacked is an end state? Could you kindly explain it?

Answer (score 4):

1."Take a rest, Felicia, you don't need to get all the firewood stacked today."

2."Take a rest, Felicia, you don't need to stack all the firewood today."

They can mean the same thing: to get something done (accomplish a task) or do something.

**HOWEVER**: 1) can mean to have someone else do the work and 2) cannot.

"I got the neighbor's son to stack my firewood".

Look at this now:
"I didn't get all my firewood stacked".

Two meanings and only the context rules here:

1. I didn't have all the firewood stacked by someone else. Only part of it.
2. I didn't accomplish the task of stacking it all myself.

Comment: This answer makes clear that context of the clauses in question is critical to an answer to the question.  It makes it clear that it is Felicia who is (personally) doing the stacking and that it is from this that she needs to take the rest.  You could construct a slightly different context in which Felicia is energetically beating her slaves to get THEM to stack the wood, so she needn't tire herself out getting them to stack by the deadline.  But this is not the obvious interpretation.  So yes:  it makes negligible difference.

Comment: @Tuffy What you say is not entirely true. Felicia, poor dear, may have been doing many things over the course of day or time referred to. So, it really doesn't change what I said.

Comment: no it doesn't.  Nevertheless, I think that the issue of context dependency was worth mentioning.